Have there been computer searches for Quine's permutations?
In "Word and Object", Quine describes what are effectively automorphisms of languages:
"The infinite totality of sentences of any given speaker's language can be so permuted, or mapped onto itself, that
(a) the totality of the speaker's dispositions to verbal behavior remains invariant, and yet
(b) the mapping is no mere correlation of sentences with equivalent sentences, in any plausible sense of equivalence however loose.
Sentences without number can diverge drastically from their respective correlates, yet the divergences can systematically so offset one another that the overall pattern of associations of sentences with one another and with non-verbal stimulation is preserved."
One could imagine with modern technology a hunt for such a possible mapping within a given corpus. Is there, for instance, a function f from English words to English words such that, when applied to every word in a given dictionary, produces a copy of that dictionary with its entries out of order? Or such a function that when applied to a large data set of online posts produces the same data set in a different order? Or perhaps such a function when applied to WordNet, preserves the relationships between words (e.g. x is a hypernym of y if and only if f(x) is a hypernym of f(y)).
Have any such searches been carried out?
